# Automorphism, relation 'greater than'

Tags: real-numbers, automorphism-group

Disclaimer: I'm very new to group theory and trying to understand it.

My book states the following:
 The image  $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow -x $ is an automorphism for $ \mathbb{R} $ relative to the order relations $\leq$ and $\geq$.

The book doesn't state proof however and I'm trying to understand it better. My question is, how do you proof this?

Is it enough to say the following:

$
-x + -y \leq -(x + y): x,y \in\mathbb{R} $ is true and therefore it is an automorphism.

Comment: Very strange. I'd say it's an anti-automorphism, since $x\le y$ implies $-x\ge-y$.

Comment: I'd say it's an automorphism of a group, or a homomorphism of ordered sets. The book claims $\phi$ to be an automorphism of what structures?

Comment: We're talking about automorphisms of groups here.

Comment: Then I have to admit, I have never heard about a homomorphism of groups relative to some ordering relation. Is it defined in your book?

Comment: My book states this: "A homomorphism is a isomorifsm if it is a bijection. ". And an isomorfism f: A $\rightarrow$ A is a automorfism. Although an homomorfism is defined in the exact way as you but then with operations instead of relations. Where an operation is defined as (x,y) $\mapsto\$ z = f((x,y)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather say that $\phi: \mathbb R \ni x \mapsto -x \in \mathbb R$ is a homomorphism of ordered sets $(\mathbb R, \le)$ and $(\mathbb R, \ge)$. Strictly speaking, they are different structures, so I wouldn't call it an automorphism, but maybe the author of your book uses a slightly different definition.

In general, $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is an homomorphism of $(A, \sim_A)$ and $(B, \sim_B)$ if
$$ \forall x,y\in A: \big((x \sim_A y) \Rightarrow (\phi(x) \sim_B \phi(y))\big)$$
In this case $\phi: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a homomorphism of $(\mathbb R, \le)$ and $(\mathbb R, \ge)$ if 
$$ \forall x,y\in \mathbb R: \big((x \le y) \Rightarrow (\phi(x) \ge \phi(y))\big)$$
For $\phi(x) = -x$ it's true, so it's a homomorphism (of ordered sets).

$\phi$ also happens to be an endomorphism of group $(\mathbb R, +)$, and for that you'd need to check the condition
$$ \forall x,y,z\in \mathbb R: \big((x + y = z) \Rightarrow (\phi(x) + \phi(y) = \phi(z))\big)$$
or equivalently
$$ \forall x,y\in \mathbb R: \phi(x) + \phi(y) = \phi(x+y)$$
It's also invertible ($\phi^{-1} = \phi$) so it's an automorphism. But in this case there's no need to consider the ordering at all.

Comment: Hmmm thanks! This already clears some stuff up in my mind but it's not tottally clear yet. Anyway huge thanks! All the pieces will probably start to fit together in a few days!

Comment: Wait! You edited the post. So it is in fact an automorphism?

Comment: Yes, it is an automorphism of the group $(\mathbb R,+)$, but I'm still confused about the part "in relative to the order relations $\le$ and $\ge$". These relations define the structure of an ordered set, and have nothing to do with the structure of a group.

Comment: Okey! I'll come back to this in two days once I finished my whole book! Anyway, huge thanks for the time you've put into answering my question!